# Handlebars js - cannot access parent object properties from loop / partial

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have the following data object:

[image]

And with this i am using the following Loop with no problem

```
Templates.Links = [
"<ul>",
"{{#each data}}",
    "<li>",
    "<div class='flex-item-button'>",
        "<div class='info noicon'>",
            "<span class='name'>{{{URL}}}</span>",
            "<span class='meta'>{{URL}}</span>",                                
        "</div>",
        "<div>",                
        "<span class='expand expand-item-details'><i class='fa fa-sort-down'></i></span>",
        "</div>",
        "<div class='additional-info'>",

        "</div>",
    "</div>",       
    "</li>",
"{{/each}}",
"</ul>",    
].join("\n");
```

This is working with no problems and withing the Each data loop i can access my data properties.  What i want to be able to do however is access the title / caml fields from within my loop.  I have tried the following with no luck.

```
{{./title}}
{{../title}}
```

I ideally wanted to use a partial within my each loop and then from within that partial access the parent node but that didn't appear to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
{{#each data}}
  ....
  {{#with ../this}}
    {{> yourPartial}}
  {{/with}}
  ....
{{/each}}
```

And in your partial, simply:

```
{{title}}
```

**Edit.**
You should implement your own helper, like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("withCurrentItem", function(context, options){
    var contextWithCurrentItem = context;
    contextWithCurrentItem.currentItem = options.hash.currentItem;
    return options.fn(contextWithCurrentItem);
});
```

And use it like:

```
{{#withCurrentItem ../this currentItem=this}}
  {{> yourPartial}}
{{/withCurrentItem}}
```

Comment: Am I now to pass in the data object as well??  So I can access the parent element and the child item?

Comment: I the case I described, your partial will be accessed with parent object
`{data: [], title: '..', caml: '' ....}`
Or do you need some more specific logic? I so, please describe it.

Comment: Basically from within my partial i need to access the current item in the data loop (each block) and the parent object properties basetemplate / title etc.